# When I use diff(), it breaks summarise()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

One of the columns I want to have after using `summarise()` is the difference between the (two) values. Each group is ALWAYS going to have two or less rows, in m case. The function I found online was `diff()`. However, I ran into a problem.
Look at this example:

```
df <- data.frame(value = runif(198),
                 id = c(
                   sample(1:100, 99),
                   sample(1:100, 99))
)

find <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  filter(count != 2)
find
```

In this case, since I'm not using `diff()`, I get this:

```
> find
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id count
  <int> <int>
1    14     1
2    39     1
```

It works fine. Now, if I include `diff()`:

```
> find <- df %>%
+   group_by(id) %>%
+   summarise(diference = diff(value), count = n()) %>%
+   filter(count != 2)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'id' (override with `.groups` argument)
> find
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# Groups:   id [0]
# … with 3 variables: id <int>, diference <dbl>, count <int>
```

It comes up with nothing. If I don't filter (it was a relatively short data frame, so I went one by one), I see those rows disappear. In a shorter example, it would be:

```
> df <- data.frame(value = runif(10),
+                  id = c(
+                    sample(1:6, 5),
+                    sample(1:6, 5))
+ )
> find <- df %>%
+   group_by(id) %>%
+   summarise(diference = diff(value), count = n())
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'id' (override with `.groups` argument)
> find
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
     id diference count
  <int>     <dbl> <int>
1     2    -0.309     2
2     3     0.474     2
3     4    -0.148     2
4     6     0.291     2
```

As you can see, the `1` and `5` rows (id) disappeared. I believe apllying `diff()` causes it, since without it, that doesn't happen:

```
> find <- df %>%
+   group_by(id) %>%
+   summarise(count = n())
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
> find
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     id count
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     2
4     4     2
5     5     1
6     6     2
```

That was the exact same data.

However, if I do it manually, `diff()` gives me an output, though in a slightly different way:

```
> diff(5)
numeric(0)
> diff(c(5, 4))
[1] -1
```

My question, then, is whether or not there is a better function to do this, or just some way for me to get the output without it erasing the one-item groups, like this:

```
  id count diference
1  1     1         1
2 58     1        58
```

I know the differenc will be the same as the id, but the reason I'm interested in this is because this is just one of the arguments I will put in `filter()`. It will be: `filter(diference != 0 || count != 2)` (once again, this isn't my original data).

Comment: `diff` outputs a vector with one less element. Try `diference = c(0, diff(value))` or `NA` instead of `0`.

Comment: That would work with this code, but if I'm going to add the argument `diference != 0`, as I put in the end, it wouldn't (if I understand correctly).

Comment: `diff` will always give you one less value. If you filter out the groups with 2 elements then you have groups with one element and the difference between that one `value` and `numeric(0)` is `numeric(0)`. If you also filter out results with `diference != 0` you **always** end up with nothing.

Comment: Also, it should be one bar only: `filter(diference != 0 | count != 2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the bar tip and for everything else. However, since it's an OR opperator, it would only add results, not filter even more. In this specific example, it would show every single row (plus or minus a few for the chance they actually do coincide), but in my dataset, most are supposed to be equal.

Comment: Also, if I do `c(0, ...)`, my output won't be 0 for the difference in case I have `count = 2`.

Comment: Unless I do `diff(c(0, value))[length(diff(c(0, value)))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what the question wants. It uses `ifelse` to compute the difference between values only if the groups have 2 rows, else it returns `value` unchanged.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(value = runif(10),
                 id = c(
                   sample(1:6, 5),
                   sample(1:6, 5))
)

find <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
            diference = ifelse(count > 1, c(0, diff(value)), value),
            .groups = 'drop') %>%
  filter(count != 2 | diference != 0)

find
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#     id count diference
#  <int> <int>     <dbl>
#1     1     1    0.647 
#2     6     1    0.0674
```